# How to speed up compile time in visual studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a very large web site solution in visual studio 2010 with lots of web forms and user controls. The problem is that every time I compile this web site, it tooks more that 5 minutes to complete. If there was an error, when I fix it and build again, compile starts from scratch and compiles previously compiled components. 
I tried the command line command asp_compiler.exe it tooks only 10 seconds. 
So, what is the difference between visual studio compile and asp_compiler command and how can I speed up visual studio compiler?

Comment: Is your code sitting on a network share?

Comment: No. It is locally on my hard drive.

Comment: If this is really a problem, you may need to break up your site into multiple assemblies.

Answer (score 2):

asp_compiler isn't doing what vs is doing. 
Reasons

Slow machine is one.

Antivirus getting in the way, put source in a specific path and exclude it for A/V

Break your code up in to seperate dlls, and minimise the number of places one can touch the other.

Answer (score 2):

in aspnet_compiler, there is a command line -c that forces aspnet_compiler to compile from scratch, I thought visual studio will add this switch (parameter) in calling aspnet_compiler
but I do not how to force vs to not do that